# How do I get a service on a remote CentOS 7 server to persist after I log out?

Tags: centos, ssh, terminal, webserver

I am experimenting with running Spring Boot apps on a remote CentOS 7 web server which has been successfully serving up apps on Apache and a stand-alone tomcat instance since day one.  However, when I `ssh` to the remote server and launch a Spring Boot app (which is in a jar that contains its own embedded tomcat instance), the Spring Boot web service `jar` runs successfully while my `ssh` connection is live, but then terminates after my `ssh` session ends.  **What specific steps do I have to take to get the `jar` containing the Spring Boot web service to continue running after my `ssh` session is terminated?**

Here is what I typed to start the app using an ssh session from my devbox many hundreds of miles away:

```
[ ~]$ cd /path/to/webservice
[ webservice]$ kill $(lsof -t -i:9000)
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
[ webservice]$ java -jar mywebservice.jar
```

Since apache forwards requests for the service internally to `port 9000`, the service is then exposed to the outside world via an apache url `somedomain.com/someurlpattern` until I terminate the `ssh` session.

Comment: Try screen (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34321/leave-remote-command-running-storing-output) or nohup and & (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Running a process in background and closing `ssh` session**

There are many ways to do so:

**1.The `nohup` command**

You can use the `nohup` command to execute commands after you exit from a shell prompt.

Example:

```
  $ nohup java -jar mywebservice.jar > /path/to/webservice/logs/mylogfile.txt &

  ## exit from shell or close the terminal ##
  $ exit
```

**2.The `disown` bash command**

Another option is to use the `disown` command as follows:

Example:

```
  $ java -jar mywebservice.jar > /path/to/webservice/logs/mylogfile.txt &
  [1] 10685
  $ disown 10685
 $ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
    10685 pts/0    00:00:00 wget
    10687 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
    10708 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
 $ logout
```

**3.The `screen` command**

You can also use the `screen` command for this purpose.

Comment: Answer updated , that should work

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to look into this.  I closed the terminal window containing the ssh session.  I also used `who` and `pkill ...` to terminate ssh sessions.  I then tested to see the web service is still working.  But I want to wait a little while to confirm that the service is not running simply due to a session that has not timed out yet.  I am somewhere on SE most days, so I will make a note to check in an answer this later.  You can ping me to reach me if you need to.  Thank you again.

Comment: The service was still working today, so I am marking this as accepted. Thank you again for helping solve this problem.